# проблема синтаксиса D3 через webpack

Tags: npm, d3.js

Разрабатываю приложение с React и D3.
К сожалению с последним знаком не так давно и очень туплю.
При подключении D3 через npm компилятор постоянно ругается на синтаксис как я понял. Я использовал как основу для изучения D3 старый учебник на метанит. Прошу помогите разобраться и решить возникшую ошибку.

Код D3 (проблема именно в его синтаксисе)

```
var mainAxis = function () {
var cur = 0;

// создание объекта svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// длина оси X= ширина контейнера svg - отступ слева и справа
var xAxisLength = width - 2 * margin;     

// длина оси Y = высота контейнера svg - отступ сверху и снизу
var yAxisLength = height - 2 * margin;

for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    if (cur < rawData[i].x) {
        cur = rawData[i].x
    }
    if (cur < rawData[i].y) {
        cur = rawData[i].y
    }
}
var sizePlus = cur/100*10;
numb = cur + sizePlus;

// функция интерполяции значений на ось Х  
var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, numb])
    .range([0, xAxisLength]);

// функция интерполяции значений на ось Y
var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([numb, 0])
    .range([0, yAxisLength]);

// масштабирование реальных данных в данные для нашей координатной системы
for (i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++)
data.push({
  x: scaleX(rawData[i].x) + margin,
  y: scaleY(rawData[i].y) + margin
});

// создаем ось X   
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleX)
    .orient("bottom");
// создаем ось Y             
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleY)
    .orient("left");

// отрисовка оси Х             
svg.append("g")       
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform",  // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо
    "translate(" + margin + "," + (height - margin) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// отрисовка оси Y 
svg.append("g")       
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .attr("transform", // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо на margin
        "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")")
    .call(yAxis);

// создаем набор вертикальных линий для сетки   
d3.selectAll("g.x-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", - (yAxisLength));

// рисуем горизонтальные линии координатной сетки
d3.selectAll("g.y-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", xAxisLength)
    .attr("y2", 0);

}
```

Код ошибки что возникла

> `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_d3__.d.axis is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по сообщению

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_d3**.d.axis is not a function

смею предположить что вы подключили d3.js зависимость версии 4, а код у вас для версии 3.

Для полной уверенности предлагаю вам предоставить package.json